# USRP B200 sample rates

Tags: transmitter, receiver, sdr

What are the possible sample rates for both transmit and receive on the [Ettus USRP B200 mini](https://www.ettus.com/all-products/usrp-b200mini-i-2/) ? This SDR uses the [AD9364](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9364.html) chip.

Does the radio use integer divisors of the master clock rate? Or does it support arbirtrary sample rates as suggested [here](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_usrp_b200.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the possible sample rates for both transmit and receive on the Ettus USRP B200 mini ?

Too many to explicitly list. Whatever clock rate the synthesizer on the ad936x can generate, divided by an integer between 1 and 512.

> Does the radio use integer divisors of the master clock rate?

Yes

> Or does it support arbirtrary sample rates as suggested here?

That page does not suggest that.

Comment: where did you see the integer decimation between 1 and 512?

Comment: Memory of the verilog source code of the ddc and Duc chains.. These are Foss.

Comment: How would a normal person find those?

Comment: Try and set a sample rate below the minimum of I think 192 kHz and UHD will just tell you there is a limit

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?